# Special Price only at certain time

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to create a catalog price rule or special price for product that only applies to itself in a certain time and day.

For example, some products of the category X should have the special price from 15:00 to 20:00 on monday.
Other products of category Y should have the special price from 20:00 to 24:00 on thursday.

This should happen every weak without activate or generate a new rule every week.

My first approach was to generate a "Catalog Price Rule" and to generate my own custom attribute field "time from" and "time to" but I didn't found a tutorial or something similar to create custom attributes in the catalog price rule generation.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Greetings

Wolv3r

*EDIT:*
Maybe there's another approach with a cronjob, but I don't know how to do the code to enable and disable the price rule.

*Edit2:*
Forget about cron-jobs. My provider isn't supporting those...

Comment: Sounds very easy. What have you tried so far in terms of code?

Comment: Nothing so far, cause I don't know how to begin with this. Never tried to get deep enough into core programming.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to set up a coupon code. You can find out how to do it [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-a-coupon-code-to-your-promotions)

Alternatively (not advised) see [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16704/) - i don't know how you customise this for one product though it's more for like when you have a sale on.

**To alleviate the “rules disappear when saving product” phenomemon:**

1. Open up Observer.php in /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/
2. Find the applyAllRulesOnProduct() method
3. At the end of the method, before “return $this;”, add:

   $this->applyAllRules( $this );

Now to address the catalog rules remaining in effect only for a limited time,  (same procedure, different method):

1. Make sure cron is set up and working properly.
2. Open up Observer.php in /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/
3. Find the dailyCatalogUpdate() method
4. At the end of the method, before “return $this;”, add:

   ```
   $this->applyAllRules( $this );
   ```
5. Open up /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml
6. Find the crontab > jobs > catalogrule_apply_all area
7. Change

   ```
    <cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
   ```

to

```
     <cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>
```

Comment: I know how to create a coupon. But the user need to enter the coupon at the checkout process to get the discount. But I want that the discount is only active at a certain time of the day, some time period the discount should be removed and later it should be activated again.

Comment: you can specify number of uses per customer. you can set it very high if you like. you can also specify a time interval.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same with the catalog price rule but with user action: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-catalog-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/catalog-price-rules for how to set them up

Comment: Yes, but with this I can't create a recurring price rule and that's what I want. I don't want to activate the price rule every week by myself.

Comment: i'll seek out an answer for you!!

Comment: sorry, but I found out that my provider isn't supporting cron jobs :(